# How to run BSDL File for a Target Microcontrol Evluation Board

Tags: trace32

I am trying to run Infineon TC297TF Evaluation Board with the Infineon provided BSDL file using Trace-32.
Can you please provide me the steps of commands I need to execute within Trace-32 to run the BSDL file and verify that some port input/output are working?
Thank you.
Regards

Comment: Do you want to do boundary scanning or do you want to debug the Aurix CPU cores?

Comment: I want to run boundary scan

Comment: Unfortunately I am not a help when it comes to boundary scanning, but have you checked out the Lauterbach "Boundary Scan User's Guide" (boundary_scan.pdf) ? You can download it from https://www.lauterbach.com/manual.html